# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of null

Tags: jquery, drupal, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using `daterangepicker` for selecting range of dates, when I click on `startdate` in `calenderpopup` it throws the error, when i select end date and apply it the filter it works fine but on selecting `startdate` or `enddate` on first it gives the error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of null".

I have tried passing start and end date initially but that did not help.

```
Drupal.CulturefeedSearch.bindDatePicker = function() {
    $('input[name="date_range"]').daterangepicker({
      startDate: datepicker("getDate"),
      endDate: datepicker("getDate"),
      presetRanges: [],
      presets : {
        specificDate: Drupal.t('Specific date'),
        dateRange: Drupal.t('Period from/to')
      },
      rangeStartTitle: Drupal.t('Start date'),
      rangeEndTitle: Drupal.t('End date'),
      doneButtonText: Drupal.t('OK'),
      dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
      earliestDate : Date.parse(),
      rangeSplitter: '-'
      constrainDates : true,
      appendTo: '.form-item-date-range'
    });
  };
```